# Connection Error trying to use Stripe payments with React & Express

Tags: reactjs, express, stripe-payments

I'm trying to integrate Stripe payments into a React project.

I've essentially copied this: https://github.com/rwieruch/react-express-stripe 
(but obviously put my own API keys in)...

The frontend seems to be working fine, but I'm getting this error when the payment declines:

```
  "OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED     xhr.js:178"
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure that the backend server is up-and-running when you make the payment request?
Check this URL: http://localhost:8080/, the backend server should respond with: 

`{
  "message":"Hello Stripe checkout server!",
  "timestamp":"2017-09-02T05:39:29.820Z"
}`

I'm asking because the error message you got is exactly the one I get if use the frontend app to make a payment without having launched the backend server.

Comment: @MichaelRambeau That did it! I feel silly.Thank you.

Comment: No problem, it happens to all of us ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ANSWERED: I just needed to launch the app from the backend folder,

```
  node index.js
```